# Let's Go! Great Anime.SE Gift Exchange! Phase 1! Ship shape and ship out!

Tags: discussion, community-events

We're knee deep in **Phase 1!** By now most of you who have opted into our [little holiday gift exchange](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1131/lets-start-the-first-ever-anime-manga-se-community-gift-exchange) should have received your matches and gotten in contact with one another!

If you haven't gotten in contact to get your Giftee's details, **do it now!**

If you haven't gotten you match for whatever reason, contact a [moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) via chat or by email at **anime.mods@madara.ninja** as soon as you can!

If you have any issues, questions, or need help on anything related to this event (including where/what to buy and how to ship), contact a [moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) via chat or by email at **anime.mods@madara.ninja*.

Make sure to ship by **Sunday, Dec. 7**! This is a soft deadline. So if you need more time **let your Giftee know!** Also **let your Giftee know when you ship** their gift!

If you have a tracking code, be sure to provide it to you Giftee. Because most of the gifters are shipping internationally, you **don't have to pay extra extra** just to get a tracking number!

If for some reason you don't hear back from your Gifter about having shipped your present (of if they need more time) by Dec. 12, contact a [moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) via chat or by email at **anime.mods@madara.ninja** and we'll get you rematched ASAP.

If you haven't received your gift from by Jan. 10 and haven't receive any notice about your gift, contact a [moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) via chat or by email at **anime.mods@madara.ninja** and we'll work something out!

Lets move onto! **[Phase 2: It's Showtime!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1182/63)** Show off your gifts, make each other green with envy!

*Note:* You just have to post a picture to show you got your gift. You don't have to be in the picture. Especially if you're camera shy!