# IT'S SHOWTIME! Phase 2! Let's show off our presents!

Tags: discussion, community-events

Dear Gifter and Giftees,

After [all that shipping](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/lets-go-great-anime-se-gift-exchange-phase-1-ship-it-out), it's the time you've all been waiting for~ It's time to show off the gifts you've gotten from your giftees! Don't worry if your's have arrived! Quantum teleportation is coming soon! It the mean time bear with the wait of snail mail!

You don't have to be in your photo, but please do post a picture of your gift and anything you want to say to you giftee! That's all! Once all the the giftees have gathered we'll post the statistics of matching for this exchange! Look forward to it!

**All members are free to post their holidays gifts**, whether they participated in the exchange or not! Strut all you want~

If you haven't received your gift from by Jan. 10 and haven't receive any notice about your gift, contact a [moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) via chat or by email at **anime.mods@madara.ninja** and we'll work something out! And we won't have you be disappointed a second time!

On behalf of the moderators at Anime & Manga SE, I wish you a happy and festive holiday, and wish you good fortune in the coming year~

[image: Maido Kurisumasu!]

Answer (score 11):

Thank you **Madara Uchiha**!

It took a while to get here, but it finally arrived. Customs must have been curious about what my gift was too!

[image]

(Kyouko-censored)

Time to open :D

[image]

Padded with some Japanese newspaper. The sports section - there seems to have been some horse racing event on recently.

[image]

Turfy \o/

Now, back to the gift! After taking out the newspaper, there was.....

[image]

**A figurine of Mikasa Ackerman from Attack On Titan!** (At this point I was shaking - half with happiness/excitement, half because I had gone to the gym just before coming home to open it)

I carefully took her out of her encasing and started checking out poses and different accessories - She's very customizable :D

[image][image]

Mikasa is my first full size figurine ( I have a Yotsuba& keydongle and a tiny non-posable Lucky Star figure), So I am super happy to get my first one today ^__^. Here are some photos of Mikasa in action

[image]
[image]
[image]

I then had to eat, because I didn't realise so much time had passed!

I started getting into photography this year, so Mikasa will be my first model :D I looked up some guides online to improve my photos. There's lots I need to try doing - Different lighting, backgrounds, angles, ... I look forward to it :D

Myself and Mikasa are so happy we could die:

[image]

BUT NOT UNTIL WE AVENGE MADARA'S GIFT IN THE NEXT SECRET SANTA!! D:<

[image]

Comment: I'm honestly curious about that Kyouko-censored...

Comment: @OshinoShinobu It was hiding my address

Answer (score 10):

Tonight I am going to post what I got, I will update this answer with peekshurs!

Sorry for being so late, I am too forgetful ._.

**EDIT:**

Courtesy of Toshinou Kyouko, a lovely christmas card :3

[image: Christmas card! :D]

Two cute plushies (chick and Totoroooo~)

[image: Plushieeeees! :D]

The first volume of the Yotsuba&! mango :3 I've not gotten round to it, but I will probably pick it up in the coming weekend :)

[image: Yotsuba&! 1]

And a Tankōbon (I believe that's the right name for it :P) of "All you need is kill"

[image: All you need is kill]

I love the plushies, they're cute :3

I'll probably read Yotsuba& this weekend and start on All you need is kill ^^ They look interesting :D

Comment: for a second I thought you got Elsie O_O

Comment: Glad you like it :D

Answer (score 9):

Seems like I am the first one to be showing off. I received the manga: "The book of human insects".

I were a bit skeptical at first by the images shown on the cover, but the title actually got my hopes up. After reading the first 50 pages or so, I really started to like the story. And managed to read the whole thing in 2 days ;)

Thanks allot for the awesome gift ^^!

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is my gift. It's courtesy of the great **kuwaly**!

Volume 6 of the awesome slice-of-life fine arts 4koma manga *GA Geijutsuka Art Design Class*!

[image: potato quality]

(Better quality ver coming soon)

[image: Actual cover]

Yay~ Thanks~

Answer (score 8):

I got the first three (or in fact the first nine, since they're 3-in-1) volumes of the manga version of Neon Genesis Evangelion from **Asada Shino**.

[image: The covers of the 3 volumes]
[image: The spines of the 3 volumes] [image: Some random pages from the 3 volumes]

I haven't had the chance to read them yet, but I'm pretty sure I'll love them (the anime is one of my favourites). I can't thank my gifter enough, and these books will have a special spot on the shelf!

**And I hope we can make the gift exchange work again next year~**

Answer (score 7):

I totally forgot that this post existed.

[image]

I got this awesome set of things--fuzzy socks, a cat glasses case, a coin purse, a few plushies, a cat hoodie-cape, some sort of egg-shaped thing, a phone charm, a Sailor Moon pen, and a Sailor Moon bow clip.

I thought I knew who my secret santa was, but I realized I have no idea, so thanks to whoever you might be.

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 6):

Just finished my first episode of Katanagatari... and then I got my gift, a Katanagatari art book!

[image]
[image]

and what's inside...

[image]
[image]
[image]

In Japanese! I need to learn how to read it :p

It's a great gift, I always want an art book. Thanks!

Comment: Keep watching! It gets better. Take is the illustrator of the original light novels, so the style is more inline with the original concepts then the anime versions.

Comment: yea every time I finished one episode I saw this book, it's pretty cool. But I must resist the urge to see next chapter :( I like their art, so colorful. And Cheerio :D

Answer (score 6):

Thank you **Oshino Shinobu** for the amazing gift!

I actually got mine a few days ago, but was too busy to post and show it off. So here I am!

I got home after a long week away, to find it waiting for me. At first I didn't know what it was, but then I understood once I saw the address. Excited, I made sure to take images before I tear it open (Okay, maybe I forgot and started tearing it open before I took the picture, don't judge me!) <sub>(Banana for scale)</sub>:

[image: Package]
[image: Inner Package]

And in the package was... An adorable Chibi figure of [Eren](http://myanimelist.net/character/40882/Eren_Yeager) from [Attack on Titan](http://myanimelist.net/anime/16498/Shingeki_no_Kyojin)!

[image: Box]
[image: Standing Box]

Along with 2 beautiful bookmarks and keychain holders

[image: Bookmarks]
[image: The whole thing]

Some poses:

[image: Box]
[image: Standing Box]

Thank you for a gift that will surely make a permanent addition to my desk :D