# A&M Gift Exchange: Show off your gifts!

Tags: discussion, community-events, tomato

Hello Anime & Manga elves!

Now that you've put all that hard work into preparing your gift, it's about time to start unwrapping your own one!

Don't worry if your gift hasn't arrived yet, sometimes good things take time. If you haven't received your gift by the 10th of January, let one of the moderators know, by email or ping us in the [Maid Cafè chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)

As we did last year, let's show off our gifts to the rest of A&M and make them jealous that they didn't take part! :)

You don't have to be in your photo, but please do post a picture of your gift and anything you want to say to you giftee! That's all!  Bonus points for those who go the extra mile !

If you didnt participate in the exchange, feel free to show off a little of your own xmas swag.

---

On behalf of all the moderators at Anime & Manga SE, We wish you a Merry Christmas, a Happy New Year and hope you'll join us again next year for another gift exchange! :)

[image]

P.S. [Check out last year's gifts too!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/its-showtime-phase-2-lets-show-off-our-presents)

Comment: I have received word that my gift has arrived back home! Once I return there from uni on the 19th I shall join in with the showing off ^_^

Comment: < received but will open it tommorow ;)

Comment: For reference, this is about the [Conspiracy Santa](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/2684/19084) event, some kind of Secret Santa. Here are the [signup](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/come-one-come-all-to-the-second-annual-anime-se-holiday-gift-exchange) and the [event start](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/am-gift-exchange-lets-start-conspiring) posts.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you **Logan M**! :)

During my lunch break I hopped down to the post office to get a package. I had ordered some xmas presents for my siblings, so I thought it was going to be that - but it was my A&M santa!

[image]

(address kyouko-censored)

I started to open it - and there is a cute glasses-girl to greet me 
and a cute dango-eating girl on the back with some rabbits too!

[image] [image]

Let's look at the present now~

[image]

ooh :) I really like this little bamboo box. it's so nicely made and presented!

And inside:

[image]

**Sushi Rolls!** Delicious.

On closer inspection they're actually little hand towels :)

[image] [image]

Thank you a lot :) These are really cool little towels.

No fanservice photos of me using them tho ;)

[image]

Comment: You should post with the towels in a tomato suit >_>~~~

Answer (score 14):

Thanks **@HashiramaSenju**!

Today, I got in the mail, a hefty assortment of delicious-looking snax from Hashirama's home country.

[image: :9]

Foreign snacks have always been a rare and delectable treat for me as there are a pletora flavors, textures, and ingredients out there waiting to be discovered. Some more healthier than others.

I've always wondered how Hashirama can subsist on just these snacks. Now I have an idea of how he does it and how delectable they are.

Additionally, I'm told there's another part coming and this is just an appetizer... Hmm I wonder what's in store for part 2! In the meantime, thanks for the yummy snax.

[image: waku waku]

To be continued in Part 2! つづく！

Comment: SNAX OP. PARUTO TU GO!!!!

Answer (score 9):

Thank you [SWard](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/15660/sward) and fellow conspirators!

Last week I got this in my mail:

[image: Air Gear Omnibus volume 1 cover]

[image: Air Gear Omnibus spread]

I never read the manga, and am looking forward to doing so! Thanks to everyone, and looking forward to next year's edition!!!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to **@DmitriMX** for my lovely gift ^_^

Here's the box

[image: box]

Open it up and we find another glasses girl! She must have run over after Tosh opened his gift.

[image: moar box]

Remove the excess paper and what do we have? A lovely Nendoroid Yamato from one of my favourite series, *Kantai Collection*! She'll be able to keep my Nendoroid Haruna company ^_^

[image: open box]

She'll stay packaged up until I return to university, but I'll make sure to update with some extra pictures once she's made it there!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you *insert name* ( Sorry, I forget your name, and can't find it q.q) For my awesome new friend !

[image]
I know I am late, but rather late then never :)

[image]
[image]
[image]